# How to normalize text in a list that is itself in a column of Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Basically, I have a dataframe of Ike's sandwiches that has three columns: Ingredients / Name / Price and the ingredients column is a list of ingredients ['x',' y',' z']

Unfortunately, when I scraped the list, it retained weird spaces and other formatting and now I'd like to amend the ingredient lists in the columns to remove spaces and force lower case.

example:

```
0    [Avocado, French Dressing, Gouda, Ham, Sal...   Al Bundy    $9.99
1    [Caesar, Halal Chicken, Marinated Artichoke ...     Backstabber     $9.99
2    [Bacon, Swiss, Turkey]  Barry B.    $8.98
3    [Avocado, Havarti, Turkey]  Barry Z.    $8.98
4    [Avocado, Halal Chicken, Honey Mustard, Pep...  Bella   $9.99
```

And the problem is:

```
> [x for x in mdf.ingredients[3:4]]
[[u'Avocado', u' Havarti', u' Turkey']]
```

Notice the spaces

I tried to doing:

```
for sandwich in mdf.ingredients:
    for ingredient in sandwich:
        ingredient = ingredient.strip()
        ingredient = ingredient.lower()
```

Which, if I print ingredient in the loop, accomplishes my goal, but does not actually change the value within the dataframe.

Is there anyway to change the values within those lists or do I need to make a whole new column with the corrected values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify `df['ingredients']`, you could assign it to a list of lists. For example, if `df` looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([([u'Avocado', u' Havarti', u' Turkey'], 'Barry Z', 8.98),
                   ([u'Bacon', u' Swiss', u'Turkey'], 'Barry B', 8.98)],
                  columns=['ingredients', 'name', 'price'])

print(df)
#                     ingredients     name  price
# 0  [Avocado,  Havarti,  Turkey]  Barry Z   8.98
# 1      [Bacon,  Swiss,  Turkey]  Barry B   8.98
```

then

```
df['ingredients'] = [[item.strip().lower() for item in lst] for lst in df['ingredients']]
```

makes `df` look like

```
                  ingredients     name  price
0  [avocado, havarti, turkey]  Barry Z   8.98
1      [bacon, swiss, turkey]  Barry B   8.98
```

---

However, having a column of lists is often not very convenient. If you want to find all the items with swiss as an ingredient, you have to loop through each row, check if that row has swiss, then return that row.

If instead you normalized the DataFrame so that each item has its own column, then that kind of search can be expressed more easily.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([([u'Avocado', u' Havarti', u' Turkey'], 'Barry Z', 8.98),
                   ([u'Bacon', u' Swiss', u'Turkey'], 'Barry B', 8.98)],
                  columns=['ingredients', 'name', 'price'])

ingredients = df['ingredients'].apply(
    lambda lst: pd.Series(True, index=[item.strip().lower() for item in lst]))
ingredients.fillna(False, inplace=True)
del df['ingredients']
df = df.join(ingredients)
print(df)
```

produces a DataFrame that looks like

```
      name  price avocado  bacon havarti  swiss turkey
0  Barry Z   8.98    True  False    True  False   True
1  Barry B   8.98   False   True   False   True   True
```

Now to find all items which contain swiss you could use:

```
In [43]: df[df['swiss']]
Out[43]: 
      name  price avocado bacon havarti swiss turkey
1  Barry B   8.98   False  True   False  True   True
```

---

By the way, this code:

```
for ingredient in sandwich:
    ingredient = ingredient.strip()
```

does not affect `sandwich` because inside the loop the variable `ingredient` is getting *reassigned* to a new value. It does not change the values in `sandwich`. Understanding this is a fundamental *ingredient* to understanding [Python's name/reference model](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Ha, you anticipated the next step in my little exercise! Thank you.